# FeatureSpacePlot freaks out with LatentSemanticAnalysis on words

Tags: plotting, machine-learning

I'm playing with [`FeatureSpacePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureSpacePlot.html) on a collection of words:

```
featWrds={"able","accept","actual","actually","added","adding","agree","answer","answers","anyway","appears","apply","approach","argument","array","asking","avoid","based","behavior","believe","best","better","built","call","case","cases","cell","change","check","clear","close","code","color","come","command","comment","comments","complex","condition","consider","context","copy","correct","correctly","course","create","data","default","define","defined","definition","difference","different","directly","distribution","documentation","duplicate","dynamic","easier","easy","edit","edited","element","elements","else","equation","equations","error","errors","evaluate","evaluation","exact","exactly","example","examples","excellent","expect","expected","explain","explanation","export","expression","expressions","fact","false","faster","figure","file","files","fine","fixed","following","form","format","formatted","found","function","functions","future","general","getting","given","gives","going","good","graph","graphics","great","guess","hard","help","helpful","hope","idea","image","include","indeed","information","initial","input","inside","instead","integral","interested","interesting","issue","just","kernel","kind","know","large","later","learn","left","length","like","likely","line","lines","link","list","lists","little","long","look","looking","looks","machine","make","makes","making","manipulate","mathematica","matrix","maybe","mean","means","message","method","mind","missing","multiple","name","need","needed","needs","nice","note","notebook","number","numbers","numerical","option","options","order","original","otherwise","output","package","parameters","particular","pattern","people","place","please","plot","point","points","possible","post","posted","precision","pretty","previous","probably","problem","problems","provide","question","questions","quite","random","range","read","real","really","reason","related","remove","replace","reproduce","result","results","return","returns","right","rule","running","said","second","sense","share","shows","similar","simple","simply","single","site","size","small","solution","solutions","solve","sorry","sort","specific","speed","start","step","suggest","suggestion","sure","symbol","symbolic","symbols","syntax","system","table","takes","taking","tell","terms","test","text","thank","thanks","thing","things","think","thought","time","times","tour","tried","true","trying","type","understand","unfortunately","update","updated","used","useful","user","users","uses","using","value","values","variable","variables","version","vote","want","wanted","welcome","windows","wolfram","work","worked","working","works","write","wrong","zero"};
```

When I try to [`FeatureSpacePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureSpacePlot.html) this with `"LatentSemanticAnalysis"`, though, I get a slew of `Dot::dotsh` errors:

```
FeatureSpacePlot[
 featWrds,
 Method->
  "LatentSemanticAnalysis"
 ]
```

I assume something is going wrong with the [`FeatureExtraction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureExtraction.html), as the example in the docs that uses `Rasterize` works, but I don't know what. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: I don't get messages if I set `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.

Comment: @BrettChampion Interesting. I bet it's using a pre-define neural net or classifier in that case... (I think that's what `ImageRestyle` does with `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` if I remember correctly from a spelunking session).